# Http 404 error for Spring's default login-processing-url(/login)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I am getting 404 error for some reason when trying to submit my custom login form to `/login`. I am using Spring-security `4.0.2` Below is my code:

Security Configuration:

```
<security:form-login default-target-url="/home" login-page="/"
        authentication-failure-url="/?error=true" />
```

Login Form:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="loginForm" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login" method="POST">
        <div class="w100">
            <div style="width: 45%; float: left;">Username:</div>
            <div style="width: 45%; float: left;">
                <form:input path="username" size="30" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w100">
            <div style="width: 45%; float: left;">Password:</div>
            <div style="width: 45%; float: left;">
                <form:password path="password" size="30" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w100">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </div>
    </form:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, missed declaring `springSecurityFilterChain`. Adding the code below fixed it.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```